# Prove $\sum_{m \geq 1} {\frac{(2m-2)!}{(1-\rho)\cdots(m-\rho)} \frac{t^m}{(1-x)^{2m-1}}} $is divergent

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, power-series

How do I show that the following power series is divergent?
$$ u(t,x) = \sum_{m \geq 1} {\dfrac{(2m-2)!}{(1-\rho)\cdots(m-\rho)} \dfrac{t^m}{(1-x)^{2m-1}}} $$
where $t$ is complex 1-dimensional, $x$ is complex $1$-dimensional, and $\rho$ is a constant.

For the context, $u(t,x)$ is the power series solution of the differential equation

$$ \left(t \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} - \rho \right)u = \dfrac{t}{1-x}+t \dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}.$$

**Note:** Feel free to add simplifying assumptions like thinking of $t$ and $x$ as real variables or assigning a value for $\rho$. Of course, in the end, I hope that my question can be answered completely.

Comment: the series diverge because individual terms does not converge to $0$ when $m \to \infty$.

Comment: @Greg Oh sorry, $x$ is only 1-dimensional. (I already corrected the question. Thanks.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ratio of the $(m+1)st$ term to the $m$th term is
$$
\frac{2m(2m-1)}{m+1-\rho} \frac{t}{(1-x)^2}.
$$
The modulus of this expression tends to infinity as $m\to\infty$. Therefore, by the Ratio Test, the series diverges for any $t,x,\rho$.